# Problem Drawing an NSRect

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, drawrect

My problem is that when the action UpdateRect calls the drawRect method, my rect doesn't update the height!

When I click on the button, I expect to see my rect height to 20 but it remains to 10. Why?

```
@implementation Graphic_view

int height = 10; //The height of my rect.

-(IBAction)updateRect:(id)sender {
    height += 10;
    //Calling the drawrect method
    [self performSelector:@selector(drawRect:)];
}

-(void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    NSLog(@"DrawRect has been called !");
    // Drawing code here.
    NSRect viewBounds = [self bounds];
    NSColor *color = [NSColor orangeColor];
    [colore set];
    NSRectFill(viewBounds);
    NSRect myRect;
    myRect.origin.x = 20;
    myRect.origin.y = 20;
    myRect.size.height = height;
    myRect.size.width = 100;
    NSColor *whiteColor = [NSColor whiteColor];
    [whiteColor set];
    NSRectFill(myRect);
} 

@end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should never call `drawRect:` yourself. Instead call `setNeedsDisplay:`

```
-(IBAction)updateRect:(id)sender {
    height += 10;
    // Schedule the drawrect method
    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}
```

Note: The iOS equivalent is `setNeedsDisplay` without an argument.

Comment: Oh ! Thank you ! But please can you take my code and insert "[self setNeedsDisplay:YES];" ? I'm worried to put it in the wrong place ;)

Comment: Come on, now. Let's not be lazy, Alberto. The better thing to do would be to read the relevant documentation since you know know there's a fundamental Cocoa drawing concept you're missing. Here's the guide you **really need to read**: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html